# JPA+Hibernate Google Cloud Sql

Tags: hibernate, maven, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-sql

As Google presented new service - Google Cloud Sql, I decided to migrate gwt+jpa+hibernate+spring+maven web application to gae.
So I have a problem while starting my app locally and on gae.
I have an error creating dao bean caused by this:

```
     [ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:625)
[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
```

So it seemed to me, that I was using jpa-1.0 instead of jpa-2.0 with hibernate (cause jpa 1.0 lacks of method:

> getValidationMode()

I checked my libs...everthing is ok - using jpa 2.0 with hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar.
But I found a promlem:
When I use my code without gae and I use another db everthing is ok. The fact is that appengine sdk include its own JPA and the version is 1.0 (quote from here [Using JPA with App Engine](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview.html))

> The JPA and datastore JARs are included with the App Engine Java SDK. You can find them in the appengine-java-sdk/lib/user/orm/ directory.
>   Copy the JARs to your application's war/WEB-INF/lib/ directory.

When an application starts, it use jpa 1.0(with no method getValidationMode() in javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo) from appengine sdk instead of mine.

So, how can I come over this problem to make my app use right jars?
Here is my persistence.xml also:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

        <!-- A JPA Persistence Unit -->
        <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit"
            transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://bragininim:test/test"></property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
                    value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"></property>

                <!-- Connection -->
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="****" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="****" />

            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some issue with Hibernate JPA support, because it used JPA 2.0 specification. But Google App Engine only support JPA1.0 specification. I also had same issue, there for I used Spring Hibernate support(instead of Hibernate JPA).

For your problem also I think better to use Spring Hibernate support.

Comment: What does that mean in practice?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an older version of hibernate (compatible with jpa 1). GAE forces these things upon you. Actually I didn't know it supports JPA - I thought only JDO is supported.

Comment: Yes, older version of hiebrnate is one way, but may be there is another?) Another promblem that gae use not full JPA. My question is how to come round gae's JPA an use JPA 2.0.

Comment: @BraginiNI : "GAE use not full JPA" - factually incorrect. If you persist to BigTable using GAE's JPA implementation (for BigTable) then it supports only some of JPAs mapping/API (obviously because JPA is designed for RDBMS only), but it supports what makes sense for that datastore. You OTOH are using RDBMS hence no relevance

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you define username and password in the persistence.xml.

I thougth that you didn't need those credentials cause the app access to DB is restricted from console administration of Google SQL Cloud, where you specify allowed app's IDs.

Comment: I prefer to create a custom user instead of using root user. You also can find useful information in this [cloud sql tutorial](http://mbraginini.com/cloud-sql-gwt-hibernate-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, I think that a GAE project for java just copies the GAE jars to the WEB-INF\lib, remove the JPA jars from DataNucleus and Geronimo and copy your Hibernate jar.
I never tried this I am guessing.

Good luck!